# how to get an image uploaded using razor page

Tags: razor-pages

Im trying to update a course model by adding an image property so that e.g the site administrator can upload 
a course image when creating a new course or when editing an existing one. 
This is my course model.

```
public class Course
    {
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Course Code")]
        public string CourseCode { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Course Name")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public int Credits { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public string SmallSescription { get; set; }
        public string BigDescription { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name ="Date Launched")]
        public DateTime DateLaunched { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }//many to many relationship with student
        public ICollection<CourseAssignment> CourseAssignments { get; set; }//many relationship with instructor.
    }
```

This is the razor page for the Create course Model.

```
@page
@model MyNamespace.CreateModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create Course";
}
<h2>Create Course</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
          @*markup removed for simplicity*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Course.Image" class="control-label"></label>
                <input  type="file" name="files" multiple class="form-control" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a asp-page="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

and this is the OnPostAsync method for the CreateModel,

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   public class CreateModel :PageModel
    {
        //other code removed for simplicity
        [BindProperty]
        public Course Course { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Page();
            }

            var emptyCourse = new Course();
            if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Course>(emptyCourse, "course",   // Prefix for form value.
                 s => s.CourseCode, s => s.CourseID, s => s.DepartmentID, s => s.Title, s => s.Credits,s => s.Image))
            {
                _context.Courses.Add(emptyCourse);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

        //image being saved
        var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
        if (files[0] != null && files[0].Length > 0)
            {
            //save the extension name as well as images folder path inside the image proiperty of every course
            }
        else
            {
            //save a default image
            }
                return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }  
    } 
}
```

I want to get the files in the HttpContext using  `var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;`, so that i can save the image path to the database.
 but `files.Count;` is zero when no image is uploaded.Therefore the code

```
if (files[0] != null && files[0].Length > 0)
        {
            //save the extension name as well as images folder path inside the image proiperty of every course
        }
```

throws an exception.
How can i solve this? I want the Image property to hold the image path for the course.
Is there a better way to get the files sent with http request?

Comment: You shouldn't use `Request.Form` anywhere in a Razor Pages application. You should bind to an `IFormFile` property instead: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/file-upload

Comment: I was following a tutorial (online) and the instructor used that technique in another application. So what is the drawback with using this technique? why shouldn't it be used?

Comment: The drawback is that you lose all the benefits that you otherwise get from working with PageModel properties, including model binding and Tag Helper support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If no files are posted, `files[0]` isn't `null`. It doesn't exist. Therefore an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is generated. If you want to work with Request.Form.Files, you should verify the value of Count instead:

```
if(Request.Form.Files.Count > 0)
{
    // you can safely access Request.Form.Files[0]
    //save the extension name as well as images folder path inside the image property of every course
}
```